# How can i calculate Caltalan numbers without a for loop?

Tags: python-2.7

I have this code for calculating Catalan numbers but in the code I used a for loop.
How can I do it without using any loops?
Thankyou for the help!
This is the code:

```
def catalan_rec(n):
    answer=0          
    lst_rec=[]
    if n==0 or n==1:
        return 1
    else:
        for i in range(0,n):
            answer+= (catalan_rec(i))*(catalan_rec(n-1-i))

        return answer
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because our [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) guidance specifies that, "Questions asking for *homework help* must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a homework writing service. I'm afraid you have to do your own work. Your instructor gave it to you in order to evaluate your understanding of the course materials. See [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6166/42757). If you're having trouble, ask your instructor for help. If you're just not willing to do the work, see your counselor for help finding a more suitable course of study. Good luck.

Comment: There is an alternative recursive formula that doesn't require a summation; use that.

Comment: There are explicit formulas and Python has a `math.factorial(x)` function.

Answer (score 0):

Direct formula from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number

```
from math import factorial

def catalan(n):
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        answer = factorial(2*n)/(factorial(n+1)*factorial(n))
    return int(answer)
```